# I want an automatically incrementing column that starts over if column 1 = ? and column 2 =?

Tags: sql, playlist

I'm building a playlist table for my spotify replica named "playlist_songs" that will look like this:

[playlist_songs table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM9AI.png)

This table is comprised of the foreign keys: playlistID, userID, and songID. I'm thinking it's primary key will be a compound of playlistID, userID, and orderID.

What I'd like is to have orderID be an automatically incrementing integer that starts over from 1 for each unique playlistID/userID combination.

I'd also like a user to be able to change the order of their songs, which would in some cases require updating all the following orderID's for the given playlistID/userID combination

How would I achieve this? Is this possible with just SQL?

Comment: Please add some examples of what you've tried. If you don't even know where to start, but you really want to use purely SQL, I would try something like this pseudocode `INSERT ((select coalesce(max(orderid),0) from thetable where playlistID= myPlaylistID and userID = myUserId) + 1) INTO thetable`.  Essentially, you are telling the insert statement to check the current max value for that user (or zero if no max value) and then add one and insert that.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I can't figure out that many DBs have an autoincrement field type (sequence) that grows on DB and grows safely, some developers want to increment this field manually, why?

If you want to manually increase the field values, you must lock these records before updating and after updating (after increasing) you can unlock this record. This is necessary so that at the same time a duplicate value may accidentally be obtained for insertion from other users. For safe increasing must use select for update commands.

[For more information how we can use this command please visit this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69840498/how-to-get-latest-new-id-from-one-tables-field-from-concurrent-transaction-in-p)

For ordering the song I recommended adding an additional field by ordering.
Update `playlistID` or `orderID` for ordering songs, this is don't recomendedded

*P.S. Sometimes, in our tables, the primary key can be a combination of two or three fields. But I recommended adding autoincrement one `id` field for the primary key, often we will be joined tables and in join conditions, we will use one condition but not 3 conditions.*